# Documentation - automatic tests and integration with GitHub

Tags: automated-tests, travis-ci

I'm working on [docs-only project](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs) (all files are HTML or MD) hosted on GitHub. I'd like each pull request to be automatically tested with spellchecker and [write-good](https://github.com/btford/write-good). I was thinking about using Travis CI for that, however I can't use the default approach where everything gets rebuilt. In case of docs-projects it's not desirable because:

- each file in the docs is independent (no need to build the whole project each time something changes),
- some spellchecker/write-good suggestions are debatable (or simply wrong) and should be ignored (e.g. because they miss context).

I don't want ALL pull requests to fail and show a long list of ignored suggestions from across the whole repo.

Is there any way for my Travis CI test to know which files/paragraphs actually changed and should be validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to restrict Travis CI tests to files that are actually modified in the pull requests.

In `.travis.yml` you have a possibility to run a script before running tests. I used it to create a list of modified files:

```
before_script:
    - git diff --name-only master > modified_files
```

Then, in `package.json` I'm passing that list to script that does actual validation.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "proofreader --file-list modified_files"
}
```

That reduced the noise, but I'd like to go deeper and validate only paragraphs that were changed.